# Luis: Access denied due to invalid subscription key

Tags: azure-language-understanding, azureportal

I am facing following issue when i try to update application on Luis using following request:

```
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/app-id-here
```

header:

```
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:paid-subscription key
```

body:

```
{
        "name": "Name of luis app",
        "description": "string"
    }
```

I am getting following error:

```
{
    "statusCode": 401,
    "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription."
}
```

I am using paid subscription from Azure portal with `westus` region. Still facing this issue.

However, This key works when I try to get top scoring intent using following request:

```
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/luis-app-id?subscription-key=subscription-key-azure&timezoneOffset=-360&q=hi
```

This is really weird as sunscription key works for `GET` request but not for `PUT` or `POST` request.

Any suggestions?

PS: I am using **paid subscription key.**

Comment: I ran into the same problem. I wanted to create an end-to-end CI/CD for a LUIS app and failed at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (subscription) keys created with a Cognitive Service LUIS resource in Azure Portal, even when added to with *Assign resource* in `luis.ai`, can only be used for runtime queries on a defined app.
The authoring endpoints on *LUIS Programmatic APIs v2.0* - to create and manage apps and their elements - can only be used with the `Authoring Key` available in the `luis.ai` portal.

More information can be found in [Authoring and query prediction endpoint keys in LUIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-keys)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have two issues you are working thru here.

First, the API you are trying to post to should read "https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/{appId}/publish". From the looks of it, you are missing the 'publish' at the end of your API call.

Second, the paid subscription key needs to be added to your LUIS app. Can you confirm it has been added? If not, follow these steps to do so:

1. Click Manage => Keys and Endpoints.
2. Next, click 'Assign resource'.
3. A window will pop up allowing you to select the tenant, subscription, and the key to use.
4. Click OK.
5. Click 'Publish' to make the newly generated endpoint accessible.

Comment: I tried this but still the same issue. Also,paid subscription key is added to your LUIS app

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add subscription primary key value in my request and also make sure you have associated your API with the product which you used the Primary key